# Is it possible to delete a user's MySite page if their User profile has already been deleted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-profile, mysite

Is it possible to delete a user's MySite page if their user profile has already been deleted? Or does their MySite page automatically get deleted when their profile is deleted?  If it does still need to be deleted, how would one do that via PowerShell for an on premise sharepoint site, since their profile no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

The **My Site Cleanup Job** is responsible for deleting user profiles and My Sites automatically of those users. This includes the following activities:

- Remove user profiles that are queued for deletion.
- If those users have a My Site, assign the user’s manager as the
  secondary site owner. Email the manager letting them know that the
  user’s My Site will be deleted in 14 days.
- Exactly 11 days after the first notification, email the manager again
  letting them know that the My Site will be deleted in 3 days.
- After a period of 14 days, delete the My Site.

More information for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9eb7c5/what-is-the-my-site-of-user-is-scheduled-for-deletion-emai/